# "Whole day" or "all day"?

Tags: grammar

Which phrase is more correct when I want to tell a client that I'm on Skype 24hrs?

> I'm there all day.
>
> I'm there whole day.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From the choice you have given

> I'm there all day

is correct.

A possible phrase using *whole* would be

> I'm there [for] the whole day

Without the article *the* your second option doesn't make sense.

Another option is

> I'm there for 24hrs

Comment: *I'm there for 24hrs* might mean I'm gone *after* the 24hrs.

Comment: @pavium, that's what I understood from the question.

Answer (score 3):

Definitely:

> I'm there all day

The other expression is ungrammatical

Answer (score 2):

*Whole* is almost always used with a preceding article (*the/a/an*), so something like *I ate whole pie* is invalid, whereas *I ate the whole pie* or *I ate a whole pie* are perfectly valid. The same situation applies to *whole day*.